# Linux - Copy directory between server using rsync

Tags: linux, rsync

I want to copy directory `foo` from server A to server B.

what is the way to do it using rsync?

- `foo` is a large directory so I need the copy will be fastest as possible.

Thank!

Comment: I want the copy to be one way, only to transfer files from A to B and not the other way around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Failing that, compress *foo* and copy the resulting archive over SSH using *scp* to your new server, then extract it.

```
tar -cvzf foo.tar /path/to/foo
scp foo.tar you@newserver:/path/to/wherever (I'd put it in /tmp)
tar -xvzf foo.tar -C /path/to/foo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rsync -a /foo/ destserver:/foo/
```

Comment: will this effect the data on A if part of the data exist on B?

Comment: what about compression? can I use the IP of B?

Comment: Questions go in questions, not comments.